# Nested Structs + Strings issues

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I'm working on a school project:I need to build an agenda in which you can insert and pick meetings etc. I used structs to get things going.
I isolated the issue to speed up things:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct year {
    struct {
        struct {
            char *time[23];
        } day[32];
    } month[13];
};

typedef struct year Year;

void main()
{
    Year agenda;
    printf("%s\n", agenda.month[11].day[31].time[3]);
}
```

Now, I met the issue while printing an entire month of meetings using a given time and a for loop. Like: printing every `12:00 meetings` of July. So the output would have looked like this:

Working part:

[image]

and that's the good part of the code.Instead,what's broken? It is working ok till you choose months from 1 to 9. Once I pick 10/11/12 I get:

Broken part:

[image]

So every time I try to print those last indices of the array of struct `month` I get strange characters instead of the empty strings. And this is also happening when increasing array size,last 3 indices are always broken.
What's wrong?

I found useless copying my original code as the issue is replicable with the small portion I pasted

Comment: @iharob
Sorry,I'm a new user and pretty new to programming.Although I'm sorry for the way I asked the question and I thank the user who fixed it for me, "please try to understand why this is wrong"  is kinda rude and didn't help me at all. Please stay away from commenting if you're not interested.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, I was trying to write an answer but then I wrote the unnecessarily rude comment. What I mean is to ask, "*Why do you expect the contents of the **arrays** to be null?*".

Comment: I have answered your question now, sorry for the previous situation.

Comment: @iharob
thanks for replying. Well,I actually can't answer you as I assumed there were random contents aswell,till I found out every portion of those sub-arrays (is it the correct word?) from 0 to 9 was containing empty strings. So the question may actually be the opposite, why so? This led me to ask it here, what's making that portion of the struct null from 0 to 9 (Jan to Oct) and filled from 10 to 12?

Comment: *null* is a kind of garbage, isn't it? Undefinite values include `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you never initialize anything at all, as a consequence your code tries to dereference an invalid pointer leading to **Undefined Behavior**.

There is very little to do to help you because it's not clear why you are trying to print the data that you haven't yet initialized.

But it appears that your confusion is related to the fact that you think that uninitialized variables are somehow initialized to `0`. That is not the case, they are left **UNINITIALIZED** for performance reasons. You need to explictily initialize everything or declare them to have `static` storage so they are initialized to `0` automatically.

The fact that some of the values are `0` is simply a coincidence, because `0` can be a garbage value too.

But generally you want to initialize them yourself, that is, you have complete control over which data is used in your allocated memory.

This is an example of how your code would run correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct year {
    struct {
        struct {
            char *time[23];
        } day[32];
    } month[13];
};

typedef struct year Year;

int
main(void)
{
    Year agenda;
    // Initialize the element of interest!
    agenda.month[12].day[31].time[22] = "Initialize me please\n";
    // Never try to write to `time[22]` because it points to
    // a string literal, and you can't modify them legaly.
    printf("%s\n", agenda.month[12].day[31].time[22]);
}
```

**NOTE**: I've changed `void main()` to `int main(void)`, if you read `void main()` somewhere that would be an outdated resource which you should avoid since modern [c](/questions/tagged/c) standards require `main()` to return `int`.

Comment: +1
The reason behind the fact I didn't initialize those arrays was that I wanted the program to just print me null content incase I hadn't inserted any value there. And it made me think I was following the right way and actually ignore initializing them to 0. It was clearly wrong isntead, as you pointed out.And yes my university book seems outdated :P.

will try to grow my experience and hopefully help others as you did with me.
That was really cool from you. Thanks!